# Why did Saul the Roman and also not being of the Sadducees sect express his disbelief in the resurrection?

Tags: jesus, paul

> Why do you people think it is unbelievable that God raises the dead?  Of course, I myself was convinced that it was necessary to do many things hostile to the name of Jesus the Nazarene. Acts 26:8-9 New English Translation

Why did it seem impossible?

The Greeks also did not believe in the resurrection and considered the body as a prison, later they tried to assassinate Paul.

Footnotes: a) Acts 26:8 tn The word “people” is not in the Greek text, but has been supplied to indicate that the second person pronoun (“you”) is plural (others in addition to King Agrippa are being addressed). b) Acts 26:8 tn BDAG 568 s.v. κρίνω 3 states, “τί ἄπιστον κρίνεται παρ᾿ ὑμῖν; why do you think it is incredible? c) Ac 26:8.” The passive construction (“why is it thought unbelievable…”) has been converted to an active one to simplify the translation. d) Acts 26:8 tn Or “incredible.” BDAG 103 s.v. ἄπιστος 1 states, “unbelievable, incredible…τί ἄπιστον κρίνεται παρ᾿ ὑμῖν…; why does it seem incredible to you? e) Ac 26:8.” Acts 26:8 tn Grk “if”; εἰ has been translated as “that” indicating indirect discourse. Acts 26:9 tn BDAG 737 s.v. οὖν 3 states, “It has been proposed that some traces of older Gk. usage in which οὖν is emphatic, = certainly, really, to be sure etc. (s. L-S-J-M s.v. 1) remain in the pap…and in the NT…indeed, of course Ac 26:9.” f) Acts 26:9 tn Grk “I thought to myself.” BDAG 255 s.v. δοκέω 2.a has “ἔδοξα ἐμαυτῷ δεῖν πρᾶξαι = Lat. mihi videbar I was convinced that it was necessary to do Ac 26:9.”

Comment: A number of your questions appear to be adversarial to the apostle Paul. That is not the purpose of this _hermeneutic_ website.

Comment: The question in the body of this item asks "*Why did it seem impossible?*", but I don't see anything being referred to as "impossible", nor is obvious what "it" refers to, nor is it obvious to whom it was that it seemed impossible.  Please rephrase the question so that it is clear what is being asked.

Comment: The question in the title of this item asks "*Why did Saul the Roman and also not being of the Sadducees sect express his disbelief in the resurrection?*". What does the Sadducees' not believing that in general all the dead will one day be resurrected have to do with Paul's belief that Jesus in particular was resurrected?
It's not at all obvious what this question is actually asking.  What is it you want to know? (And please make the body and title questions be the same.)

Comment: This series of question is odd - nothing here suggests that Paul disbelieved the resurrection!! Paul is asking why his hearers disbelieved the resurrection.  This is rather simple!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the quoted verses says that Paul ever disbelieved in the resurrection. In fact there is no direct connection between them, because v9 starts a new theme.

In the RSV, vv4-8 are a distinct paragraph, and that does make sense in terms of the content. v5 declares that he has lived as a Pharisee, and v6 declares that he is on trial precisely because he DOES "hope in the promise made by God to our fathers".  v8 identifies this hope as "that God raises the dead". It is the accusers of Paul who disbelieve this teaching, not Paul himself. THEY are the ones who "think it incredible".

Then vv9-11 are a paragraph about his behaviour when he was persecutor of the church, designed to lead up to the account of the Damsacus road experience from v12 onwards.